# Как организовать работу с системами контроля версий для разработки нескольких проектов с общей основой?

Tags: git, svn, контроль-версий

Стоит следующая задача: мне надо создать хранилище, где будут разные файлы скриптов (например, A). Также будет хранилище, где будет стандартный набор файлов для начала программирования сайта (например, B). Когда я создаю новый проект — создается новое хранилище (например, C).

Теперь мне нужно в С перенести стандартный набор из хранилища В. Потом мне нужно из А перенести 2 скрипта в С. После этого я вижу, что в стандартных файлах (которые хранятся в В) есть ошибка. Я её исправляю и хочу залить как на В, так и на С. И так далее. То есть мне надо с ними 3-мя работать одновременно.

Уже пробовал git и svn, ничего не получилось. *Решение через git submodule не подходит*, т.к. общие файлы нужно редактировать в конкретных проектах, и при этом иметь возможность подтягивать изменения в этих же файлах из основного набора.

В какой системе контроля версий и каким образом можно организовать хранилища для решения этой задачи?

Comment: Почему бы не упростить схему, и не объединить A + B в один репозиторий? В общем случае git предпочтительнее, git submodule в помощь.

Comment: задача как раз стоит в том, что бы использовать много репозиториев одновременно

Comment: git submodule - немного не то, оно создаст отдельный каталог, а мне нужно просто клонировать файл и что бы он уже участвовала в основном проекте

Comment: то есть вы делаете `git clone <repo-b> project-c` ?

Comment: да, я клонирую основной проект, потом хочу докинуть файлы с другого, и хочу иметь возможность закидывать файлы как на первый так и второй

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> **Важно:** если для вашего языка есть хорошая система управления зависимостями, то приведённое здесь решение лучше не использовать. Потому что если она есть, гораздо проще сделать из основы **отдельную библиотеку** и устанавливать её, как **зависимость**. В Node.js — NPM-пакет, в Ruby — gem, в PHP — пакет Composer, в Rust — crate, и т. д.
>
> А то получится избыточность и могут добавиться хлопоты при обновлениях, которых можно избежать, изначально не используя систему контроля версий не по назначению.

### `git` может такое.

Вообще у меня впечатление, что `git` может всё. Правда, механизм работы не слишком простой, нужно понимать, как он при этом будет работать.

Поскольку `git` по природе своей распределённый, я сэмулирую ваш порядок работы **в одном локальном репозитории на нескольких несвязанных ветках**: `a`, `b` и `master`. Изменения в этих ветках могут запросто появляться из других репозториев (разные ветки могут следить за разными серверами!), но при использовании такой методики у вас локально должен быть репозиторий, в котором есть все три.

#### Поехали по пунктам:

Положим, что `git init` вы сделали, а С (сам проект) лежит в ветке `master` (что совершенно необязательно).

> создать хранилище, где будут разные файлы скриптов (например, A)

Делаем "несвязанную ветку":

```
git checkout --orphan a
```

Зачищаем папку и индекс, чтобы начать с чистого листа:

```
git reset && git clean -f
```

Делаем коммит с фигнёй:

```
echo 'скрипт' | tee script_a_1 script_a_2
git add .
git commit # Тут вас попросят ввести сообщение для коммита
```

> хранилище, где будет стандартный набор файлов для начала программирования сайта (например, B)

То же самое.

```
git checkout --orphan b
git reset && git clean -f
echo 'скрипт' | tee script_b_1 script_b_2
git add .
git commit # Сообщение для коммита
```

> Когда я создаю новый проект - создается новое хранилище (например, C).

Будем считать, что это ветка `master`. И в настоящий момент она должна быть пуста, для `git` это означает, что она не существует, поэтому придётся делать её заново:

```
git checkout --orphan master
git reset && git clean -f
```

> Теперь мне нужно в С перенести стандартный набор с хранилища В.

Мёрдж:

```
git merge b
```

При этом произойдёт fast-forward до `b`, `master` будет совпадать с веткой `b`. Это нормально. Ведь на этом этапе состояния файловой системы проекта совпадают, верно?

> Потом мне нужно с А перенести 2 скрипта в С.

Мёрдж с `a`, но на сей раз с "тормозами", чтобы прямо перед коммитом `git` остановился:

```
git merge --no-commit --no-ff a
```

Зачем? Затем, что вам не все файлы нужны. На этом этапе вы можете убрать из индекса ненужные вам файлы из индекса с помощью `reset`, зачистить оставшееся и закоммитить результат:

```
git reset script_a_2
git clean -f
git commit
```

Теперь немного "поработаем", для вида:

```
echo work > work
git add work
git commit
```

> в стандартных файлах (которые хранятся в В) есть ошибка. Я ей исправляю и хочу залить как на В...

Поскольку у вас (семантически) `master` основан на `b`, а не наоборот, ошибку вам надо починить именно в `b`, чтобы потом изменения "растеклись" (не автоматически!) по тем, кто ею пользуется. Идём в ветку `b` и чиним:

```
git checkout b # clean уже не нужен, т. к. ветка не пустая
echo script > script_b_1 # Ну, допустим, что кириллица не переварилась. Мало ли.
git add script_b_1
git commit
```

На этом этапе, если репозитории с `b` и `master` всё-таки разные, должен быть `git push` ветки `b` в соответствующий репозиторий, а в репозитории проекта нужно сделать `git pull --ff-only` (`--ff-only` разрешает только перемотку ветки — чтобы ваши изменения не "затекли" в `b`) в ветке, которая за тем репозиторием следит. Это уже отдельная тема, если интересно, расскажу и об этом.

> ...так и на С.

Переходим в ветку с проектом:

```
git checkout master
```

И делаем мердж ветки `b` в проект.

```
git merge b
```

Готово. Да, вот так просто!

После проделывания вышеописанных манипуляций, я получил в `master` следующую схему из коммитов (`git log --graph`):

```
*   commit 2e9219cb2922f70382a8f069fdc917bdbfccd4b8
|\  Merge: 2cc463a 1fc0b61
| | Author: Имя <адрес>
| | Date:   Sun Dec 27 14:46:12 2015 +0300
| | 
| |     мердж фикса
| |   
| * commit 1fc0b61c1017acf4b4ef1941e1cdcb01a7e86be4
| | Author: Имя <адрес>
| | Date:   Sun Dec 27 14:41:23 2015 +0300
| | 
| |     фикс основы
| |   
* | commit 2cc463ae97500bff4a304990aa4e42159da96fe9
| | Author: Имя <адрес>
| | Date:   Sun Dec 27 14:38:37 2015 +0300
| | 
| |     работа
| |     
* |   commit cfa122c954f77b3282f51511f94bc6d97c95d569
|\ \  Merge: 7da066c f9304d8
| |/  Author: Имя <адрес>
|/|   Date:   Sun Dec 27 14:31:20 2015 +0300
| |   
| |       мердж с удалением лишних
| |   
| * commit f9304d82d89600add270544bec32cd6661a8c150
|   Author: Имя <адрес>
|   Date:   Sun Dec 27 13:46:39 2015 +0300
|   
|       скриптики
|  
* commit 7da066c234216057ff19775a355342ed501fe9a4
  Author: Имя <адрес>
  Date:   Sun Dec 27 13:54:01 2015 +0300
  
      основа
```

И для наглядности, перерисовал:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо, но я думал это можно сделать проще(

Comment: @Diefair это выглядит сложно, т. к. гит довольно весело ведёт себя с пустыми ветками и мне приходится делать дополнительные действия. На практике это на 90% "пуш в хелперы", "пул в проекте", "мёрдж хелперов в проект". Всё.

Comment: @Diefair я добавил более наглядный рисунок репозитория. Может, поможет решить смежные и вопросы с Git.

Comment: Это решение технически очень крутое, позволяет залезть в самые дебри гита и вернуться победителем. Но почему бы не использовать субмодули, они же проще? )

Comment: @NickVolynkin см. комментарии к вопросу :)

Comment: @D-side а, ну да, он же хочет эти файлы потом менять. А через наследование и override не решаются такие задачи? Я-то не знаю, я нуб во фронтенде. )

Comment: Устроил конкурс для привлечения внимания. Пусть знакомятся с orphaned branches.

Comment: @NickVolynkin я тоже не фронтендщик, но по-моему, любая нормальная система модулей для языка делает это решение малополезным, т. к. детали, которые могут меняться со временем, можно упаковать в отдельную библиотеку и апгрейдить её как отдельную зависимость при необходимости (Rails с этим справляется, например). То есть, даже без подмодулей. А orphaned branches тут только для демонстрации, ожидается, что на практике это будут отдельные репозитории. Хотя пример может и неплохой.

Comment: @D-side пример отличный хотя бы для того, чтобы 1) ещё раз понять, что в git всё является графом и 2) поучиться понимать и проектировать модель работы с контролем версий с учётом того что всё является графом.

Comment: Финиш. )) Кстати, в чём нарисован граф коммитов? Какой-нибудь инструмент для диаграмм?

Comment: @NickVolynkin спасибо! Почти набралось серебро! :D Нет, Inkscape, векторный редактор общего назначения. Я вроде даже в чате писал, когда закончил этот ответ.

Comment: @D-side судя по моему опыту, теперь на этот ответ плюсы будут падать чаще, чем раньше, т.к. вопрос в [топе по метке](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git). Так что серебро наберётся скоро.

Answer (score 6):

Если не хочется делать несколько веток, отслеживающих разные сервера, и так далее [как в другом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/478322/201364), то можно работать аналогично тому как разрабатываются крупные распределённые проекты вроде [ядра Linux](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/SubmittingPatches) или [языка Go](https://golang.org/doc/contribute.html#mail) - через файлы с патчами, с тем лишь отличием что ничего никому не нужно посылать по почте.

1. Вносим изменения в файлы проекта *C*, которые нужно перенести обратно в *A* или *B*:

   ```
   git add -p; git commit
   ```
2. У нас получился коммит в котором меняются файлы имеющие место **только** лишь в *A* или *B*, обязательно не одновременно. Проверяем это с помощью `git show`.
3. Экспортируем этот коммит в файл:

   ```
   git format-patch -1
   ```

   Команда создаёт файл с изменениями вида `0001-example.patch`.
4. Переходим в проект *A* или *B*, применяем там ранее полученный патч:

   ```
   git am ../ProjectC/0001-example.patch
   ```
5. В лучшем случае ничего больше делать не надо.
6. В худшем случае может потребоваться решить обычные конфликты, которые появляются при слиянии. [Например, так](https://gist.github.com/sanmai/c5f37d38c73b51f12d96):

   ```
   find . -type f -name \*orig -print -delete
   find . -type f -name \*rej -print -delete
   patch -p1 < .git/rebase-apply/patch
   find . -name \*.rej |
   while read rej
   do
     echo $rej
     wiggle -r ${rej%.rej} $rej
   done
   ```

Таким же образом изменения переносятся обратно. Вот и всё.

Ограничение остаётся всё то же самое: для удобного и простого отслеживания истории файлы в проекте *C* должны оставаться там же где и в проектах *A* и *B*.

То же относится к работе с несколькими проектами: чтобы переносить какое-то изменение из проекта-шаблона *B* в копии *С1*, *С2*, *С3*... При любом подходе вам нужно будет писать программу или скрипт.

#### Недостатки такого подхода

Недостатки очевидны - это относительно ручная работа для переноса изменений (которая в принципе поддаётся автоматизации), но и о достоинствах забывать не стоит.

#### Достоинства такого подхода

Самое очевидное достоинство такого подхода: простота при использовании и отсутствие необходимости помнить где какая ветка, а значит меньше шансов сделать `merge` не того не туда. Меньше ошибок - меньше времени на их исправление. Больше времени на более интересные занятия.

Ещё одно достоинство: конфиденциальность. Если вам когда-либо нужно будет дать доступ к Git посторонним (например, вашему подрядчику для проведения рутинных работ), то посторонний не увидит всей-всей истории изменений в проектах *A* и *B*, которая обязательно попадет в *C* при любом слиянии веток. Например, если вы [начинаете новый проект из шаблона](http://www.alexeykopytko.com/2011/git-forget.html) так:

```
# начинаем новый проект
git clone TemlateB NewProjectC
cd NewProjectC
git reset $(echo "NewProjectC Started" | git commit-tree HEAD^{tree})
git remote rm origin
# спустя некоторое время
git am ../TemlateB/0001-example-fix.patch
```

То в такой ситуации в проекте *C* посторонний увидит только какой-то самый недавний коммит и коммиты-исправления, а не всю историю проектов *A* и *B* за всё время. Естественно, посторонний не увидит и изменений из других проектов, аналогичных *C*.

Масштабируемость - ещё одно достоинство этого подхода. Поддерживать 30-50-80 копий проекта? Нет проблем! Делегировать работу над каким-то проектом подрядчику? Проще простого! Убрать какой-то проект в архив с глаз долой? Нет проблем! Вернуть из архива? Легко!

Теперь представьте себе сколько экранов будут занимать 80+ веток по каждому из когда-либо начатых проектов. Даже и говорить не стоит о том чтобы убрать какую-то ветку в архив или делегировать что-то кому-то. Нет, нельзя сказать что это невозможно...

Comment: *отсутствие необходимости помнить где какая ветка* -- это решается путём заведения для себя каких-нибудь правил именования для веток, на манер тех, что использует *Git Flow*. Всё-таки чтобы смерджить ветку, придётся ввести и увидеть её название. Но решение тоже неплохое, да.

Comment: Всё так, но зачем *решать* проблему которую можно *не создавать* изначально?..

Comment: Чтобы решить *другие* проблемы, которые уже есть, разумеется :)

Comment: Один-другой проект по схеме с ветками поддерживать - это семечки. *Проблемы* возникнут когда у вас будет десятки проектов с отдельной веткой под каждый :)

Comment: Вариант на ветках имитирует порядок работы в случае, когда проект находится в одном репозитории, а его основа в другом. На нескольких ветках он только продемонстрирован. Я не могу себе представить реалистичной ситуации, когда проект мерджится из десятков отдельных веток с разными файлами. А куча проектов по веткам была вполне себе обычным зрелищем, когда биллинг гитхаба шёл по количеству приватных репозиториев; `git worktree add` помогает не съехать с катушек при таком порядке работы.