# git push в указанный репозиторий

Tags: git, github

Я подключил 2 репозитория.

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/мой_аккаунт/репозиторий_1.git -> здесь много файлов
git remote add index https://github.com/мой_аккаунт/репозиторий_2.git -> тут пусто
```

После этого я сделал изменения и решил закомитить их на первый репозиторий:

```
git add index.php
git commit -m "Comit"
git push origin master
```

Все ок.
Потом я хочу эти же изминения закомитить на второй репозиторий:

```
git push index master
```

и в пустой репозиторий залились все файлы, а не только index.php. Почему?

Comment: Ответ на вопрос "Почему?" – потому что так работает Git.

Comment: Вы забыли написать что вы хотели сделать, а то сейчас только констатация фактов правильной работы Git

Comment: можно ли сделать  что бы заливался только index.php? то есть, только один файл

Answer (score 3):

Как верно пишет Mira, в Git можно индексировать (а следовательно, и сохранять в коммит) отдельные файлы и даже строки (для бинарных не получится). Но после этого Git оперирует только коммитами целиком. Вы не можете заливать на удаленный репозиторий часть коммита — только целый.

Каждый коммит содержит не один файл — он содержит «снимок» всей рабочей области проекта. То есть когда вы сделали коммит с index.php, то в нем на самом деле содержится:

- Новый index.php
- Всё, что было в предыдущем (родительском) коммите.

Родительский, соответственно, содержит изменения, которые сохранены в нём плюс всё из его предка. И так далее до самого первого коммита в истории проекта. Вот поэтому в репозиторий и заливаются каждый раз все файлы.

Подробнее тут: [Каким образом git сохраняет изменившуюся строку при коммите?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/126895/181472)

Если вам нужно заливать только один файл, то можно подумать о реализации, но сначала нужна четкая постановка задачи, которую вы так пытаетесь решить.

Answer (score 2):

В гите возможно коммитить не только отдельные файлы, но даже только определенные строки.

Для этого зайдите в графический интерфейс (`git gui&`) и там в окошке слева - сверху текущие изменения, слева - снизу - изменения подготовленные для коммита. И вы можете по одному файлы убирать-добавлять, нажимая на иконку файла.

Так же для строк: выделяете в основном окне строки, и в меню выпадающем по нажатию правой кнопки мыши выбираете `"stage lines"` (подготовить к коммиту) либо `"unstage lines"` (убрать из коммита)

После чего нажимаете `commit` и в него попадут только выбранные файлы либо строки.

Команда `push` применяет все обновленные коммиты полностью на удаленный репозиторий, тут уж без вариантов. То есть если относительно первого репозитория у вас изменился один коммит - обновится только он, если относительно второго - есть изменения для нескольких коммитов - они обновятся все.
Команда `push` фактически не "заливает файлы" а обновляет удаленный репозиторий до состояния локального, досылая недостающие объекты.

Answer (score 1):

### Потому что ветка одна и та же.

**А ветка состоит из "верхушки" и всех её предков (дерева коммитов).**
`push` и `pull` загружают дерево **целиком**, пока у коммитов рекурсивно не перестанут находиться предки. То есть, будет точно воспроизведено состояние репозитория на "верхушке" ветки.

Если вы хотите отделить часть файлов, храните их **в отдельной ветке** (я вам уже вчера [рассказывал, как](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/478322/181100)) и делайте мёрджи только **из** этой ветки, а не **в** неё при необходимости внести в эти файлы изменения. Тогда коммиты, меняющие эти файлы, никогда не сошлются на другие файлы проекта и не будут лежать в ветке.

В ветке `b` команда `git merge a` заставит ветку `b` ссылаться на ветку `a`, **но не наоборот**. Ветка `a` ничего об этом мердже не узнает, она сама по себе.

Рассматривайте "утилиты" и "основу" как разные проекты.