# Автоматический перенос багфикса из одного проекта в другой

Tags: git, bitbucket

Подскажите, пожалуйста - есть основной проект в GIT-репозитории (неизмененное ПО). Есть другие форки данного проекта в GIT (заточенная версия ПО под клиента).

Как я могу сделать автоматический перенос багфикса с форка в основной репозиторий?

Использую `bitbucket`.

Comment: Автоматический в каком ключе? Вы хотите, чтобы система сама их обнаруживала и применяла? Или хотите отдельно взять основной репозиторий и указать "перенеси багфикс Х"? Приведите пример ожидаемого "идеального поведения".

Comment: Например, я слил ветку bugfix/01 в ветку master в форке. У меня автоматически эти коммиты залились в ветку мастер оригинального репозитория.

Comment: А как понять, что этот багфикс не относится к адаптационному коду под клиента?

Comment: Предположим, что я сам это буду понимать. перенесу эти коммиты в basebugfix/01.

Comment: Тогда в чём заключается автоматизация?

Comment: Немного неправильно объяснил. Такие багфиксы должны раскидываться не только на базовый репозиторий но и на другие форки.

Comment: Ага... [я тут описывал похожий сценарий](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478100/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8/478322#478322). Как считаете, вопрос дублирует ваш?

Comment: У вас это разные ветки. У меня разные проекты. Но, спасибо большое. Покапаюсь.

Comment: Да, я именно об этом моменте упомянул ближе к началу ответа :)

Comment: По-прежнему интересно, пригодился ли вам ответ D-side и что получилось в итоге. )