# Как ограничить стороннему разработчику видимость участников проекта

Tags: git, github

Задача - подключить стороннего разработчика к проекту на Github, но с условием, что он не должен видеть разработчиков организации и тех, кто совместно с ним ведет разработку проекта - создает коммиты и т.п. Как исключить видимость членов организации я нашел - "Outside collaborators". Но при этом "чужак" продолжает видеть тех, кто совместно с ним работает над "его" проектом.

Есть ли решение моего вопроса ?

Comment: имена авторов коммитов он все равно будет видеть - это метаинформация, которую так просто не утаить (ну разве переписать гит). Поэтому, либо не показывайте проект, либо давайте просто сорцы, а он Вам будет патчи присылать.

Comment: Думали про этот вариант. Не получится - дать доступ - обязательное условие. Думали и про клон проектов, но запутались с синхронизацией

Comment: при клоне проекта имена авторов коммитов все равно сохраняются. Имя автора коммита - это неотъемлемая часть коммита. Может проще NDA подписать?

Comment: Ситуация такая, что сторонний разработчик от конкурента :( и взять придется. (Долгая история) - думали еще дать ему отдельный проект, чтобы он был в нем один, но опять же - синхронизация

Comment: Вот поэтому и решайте это юридически. Подписывайте с ним соглашение.Где так и будет написано "это можно, это можно, а за это - 100500 баксов выплатить".

Comment: :) ну не увидим мы в лицо это разработчика. Только данные для подключения к гиту

Comment: А в чем проблема отправить ему письмо? даже электронное.

Comment: Настройте прокси-репозиторий на любом сервере, который будет постоянно обновляться из github и наоборот и дайте ему доступ к этому прокси.

Comment: м, а прокси будет прятать имена коммитеров?

Comment: Сохдать всем специальных прользователей user1, user2...? Ну будут они видеть сколько пользователей, но не будут знать кто это.

Comment: у меня вопрос... ну увидит он имена разработчиков? в этом криминал таится или что?)))

Answer (score 1):

1. Делаете отдельный репо в котором не будет никаких коммитов. Забыть всё можно так:

   ```
   git reset $(echo "Чистый старт" | git commit-tree HEAD^{tree})
   ```
2. Даёте доступ на этот репо тому человек, смотрите его PR, принимаете и всё как обычно.
3. По мере выполнения работы [переносите коммиты в основной репо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478100/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80/599715#599715).