# Разные ветки в GIT с общими классами

Tags: java, git, branch

Есть несколько проектов, у которых одно ядро (Несколько классов, отвечающие за загрузку контента, загрузка контента на этих проектах идентична), но остальные классы специфические, у каждого проекта свой функционал, один может играть аудио контент, в другом проекте реализация проигрывания видеоконтента.
Так вот, я хочу сделать две разные ветки на GIT'e, один с аудиоплеером, другой с виеоплеером, но у обоих должно быть одинаковое ядро, если я принесу изменения в ядро, то эти изменения должны приняться в обоих ветках. Но я вообще не знаю как это реализовать на GIT'e, гугление результатов не дало. Возможно есть тут люди, которые такое реализовывали?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как организовать работу с системами контроля версий для разработки нескольких проектов с общей основой?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478100/...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам надо разбить проект на несколько модулей. В таком случае вы сможете отдельно или даже параллельно написать коды на них. Потом сможете добавлять зависимостей в одну кучу.

Вот ссылка на [Руководство по работе с несколькими модулями](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) если вы собираете проект на Maven.

Вот ссылка на [Многопроектные сборки](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) если вы собираете проект на Gradle

Да, кстати можете создать отдельную git ветку (branch) для каждого модуля без проблем. Они не будут мешать друг другу.

Answer (score 2):

Есть два способа.

- использование [сабмодулей](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8).
  Свой проект разделяете на три проекта - ядро (там общие классы), и два проекта с видео и обычным плеером.
  Этот способ как бы правильный, но для новичков может быть "неожиданным и сложным".
- использование препроцессора/отдельных проектов. То есть, делается два файла проекта, которые живут в одном каталоге. Дальше все логично. От гита не зависит.

Comment: Не сказал бы, что первый способ - правильный. В окружении, где приходится часто менять ветки, следить за подмодулями - боль.

Comment: я написал явно - "как бы правильный".