# Несколько проектов с одним ядром в одном Git репозтории

Tags: git, bitbucket

## Все привет!

Столкнулся с трудностью выбора подхода для ведения нескольких проектов на одном репозитарии.

## Дано

- имеем некоторое ядро кода, общее для всех проектов
- проекты все разные и независимые, но ядро используют одно
- разработка ведётся параллельно как базового ядра, так и проектов
- ядро выступает как master

## Желаемый результат

- транслировать изменения ядра во все дочерние проекты
- изменения в дочерних проектах должны быть изолированными
- хранить все изменения в Git
- проекты и ядро должны находиться на локальном компьютере для быстрого доступа
- ветки никогда не объединяются в одну, а идут параллельно

Должно получиться что то типа такого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### У кого какие идеи есть по решению такой задачи?

Comment: Несколько проектов в одном репозитории? Жесть... Так не стоит делать.

Comment: И, судя по "ядро выступает как мастер" -- вы так и не отделили ядро (core) от проектов. Т.е. может даже вы и хотели сделать (допустим) какой-то фреймворк для сайтов и пяток сайтов на этом фреймворке -- но получается слишком сильно связанная архитектура. В такой ситуации надо честно делать отдельные репозитории и для сайтов и для ядра. Аналогия понятна?

Comment: Я не могу этого делать. Ядро - это протокол обмена данными между устройствами, там парсеры, API и куча другого. Поэтому обновлять каждый проект по отдельности это точно жесть...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как организовать работу с системами контроля версий для разработки нескольких проектов с общей основой?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478100/)

Comment: @ОлегПеревышин и что, что по отдельности? Все нормальные проекты сделаны именно так. Нужно использовать какую-нибудь систему обновления зависимостей, которая будет автоматически устанавливать обновления ядра из гит-репозитория

Comment: Вообще, наверно, это ваше «ядро» наверно можно назвать словом «фреймворк», но, видимо, он ещё не совсем нормально оформленный фреймворк, если вы его не можете просто так взять и отделить

Comment: он постоянно развивается, добавляются новые функции, возможности и т.д. он врят ли когда то отделится вообще, потому что это основа (ствол дерева), а проекты - это крона... как то так примерно
Вот например появилась новая функциональная особенность (например обновление устройства с сервера), я хочу чтоб эта возможность появилась у всех устройств сразу.

Comment: Вам всё равно придётся обновлять каждый проект по отдельности, делая мердж (и, потенциально, разгребая возникшие конфликты). Никаких существенных преимуществ перед существованием в форме отдельной зависимости у такого жонглирования ветками нет.

Comment: @ОлегПеревышин все «взрослые» фреймфорки постоянно развиваются. Тем не менее, все они распространяются и обновляются отдельно от своей «кроны». Если вы не можете их разделить, значит вы ещё программист-новичок и не умеете в грамотную архитектуру :)